# What are schemas for datasets in Azure data factory and what are they used for?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, schema

I am trying to learn about Azure data factory. I have been laerning about datasets and i understand what they are and what they are used for. The thing that confuses me are schemas. Does anyone know what it means and what they are used for? Please see the picture below:

[image]

To look at different youtube videos

Answer (score 0):

Schema is basically the structure of the dataset .
Schema of the dataset, represents the physical data type and shape
Like structure of your file in case file or table in case if SQL etc.

It is used to create a mapping between source and/or sink during copy activity etc

[image]